# Can't create a Python 3 notebook in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/spark-jupyter-dataproc/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5) and I'm stuck when I want to create a new Jupyter Notebook (Python 3). The cluster is created using this command:

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create ${CLUSTER_NAME} \
 --region=${REGION} \
 --image-version=1.4 \
 --master-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
 --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
 --bucket=${BUCKET_NAME} \
 --optional-components=ANACONDA,JUPYTER \
 --enable-component-gateway
```

When I accessing the JupyterLab and try to create a new notebook I can see:
[image]
and then
[image]

console works fine

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Dataproc team is handling this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a consequence of the new feature to support storing notebooks either in GCS or on the local disk.

To enable that, the top-level directory inside of Jupyter (and JupyterLab) was made into a virtual, read-only directory that just links to the GCS and local disk locations via virtual subdirectories. The intention is that you choose a storage location by navigating this virtual file hierarchy.

So, if you try to create a file at the top-level, you will get an error because that top-level is read-only, but if you navigate into one of the subdirectories, then things will work as expected.

The user experience around this clearly needs to be improved, and that error message is not helpful at all, so we are working on improving the experience here.

However, if you choose one of the two storage options (by navigating into one of the subdirectories), then things should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please navigate to `GCS` or `Local Disk` on the left panel as an intermediate solution, it should work afterwards.