# Cannot access GCS folder in Dataproc JupyterLab after July 10 upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-dataproc

In Dataproc, everything was fine but after a recent (automatic) upgrade (I think it was [July 10](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/release-notes#July_10_2020)), after I create a new cluster in Dataproc (Gateway option checked for accessing applications) and specify an existing bucket where I had all my notebooks, I cannot see my old notebooks stored in Google Cloud Storage.

When I go to JupyterLab I can now see two folders, GCS and Local. I assume my old notebooks should be in the GCS folder as it should point to my bucket, so I double-click on the GCS folder but I am getting an **Invalid response** error (500).

**EDIT:** thanks for que suggestion. The question is indeed related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905434/cant-create-a-python-3-notebook-in-jupyter-notebook) where the advice is to navigate inside the GCS folder or the Local folder before trying to create a notebook. But my problem is: I cannot navigate into GCS because when I try, I get the Invalid response error 500.

Comment: If you pin to an older version like `1.3.60-debian10` does it continue to work the way it used to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create a Python 3 notebook in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905434/cant-create-a-python-3-notebook-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Nope, I cannot even navigate into the GCS folder because I get error 500 when I try.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

As suggested by Dennis, if I use version 1.3.60-debian10 (I had to use using the Cloud Shell command line to specify the exact version since it is not among the options), it works exactly as before. Thanks!