# Can not open Jupyter notebook on Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, dataproc

I have created GCP dataproc cluster but I have enabled gateway and selected Anaconda and Jupyter notebook , but when I **try to open jupyter notebook** , the follwing message pops-us :

[image]

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here in this satackoverflow answer :
[Can't create a Python 3 notebook in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62905434/cant-create-a-python-3-notebook-in-jupyter-notebook)

Simply, before opening the notebook , navigate to one folder e.g, GCS